# Утилиты для работы с внешним жестким диском.

Tags: hdd

Подскажите утилиты, программы, которые могут сделать часть жесткого диска запароленым, зашифрованным.
Возможно еще полезные утилиты, которые могут делать что-то полезного и интересного с внешним винтом.

**Спасибо.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если требуется шифровать отдельные файлы, то подходит [GnuPGP](http://gnupg.org/). Если требуется шифровать более значительные объемы (например, целый диск), то подходит [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). Оба средства - бесплатны, доступны в исходниках, работают под Windows, Mac, Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант попробуйте это: [BitLocker](http://www.windowsnomer7.ru/2010/01/bitlocker.html).